# Two low flying large planes made bank turn - not on radar

Tags: air-traffic-control, airline-operations, radar, stealth, online-tracking

On Thursday March 10, 2022, at approx. 7:30pm in Monroe, Connecticut, I witnessed two full sized planes following one another extremely low and then make an incredible bank turn.

These planes did not show up on radar apps/websites. They came up from the South and banked South East, most likely returning in the same direction they came from.

I have never seen a plane that low be so quiet…and then came another one right on its tail. My guess is they were military or some sort of test run from Sykorsky Memorial Airport.

If anyone has any info on how to find out what happened, I would really appreciate it.

It’s been driving me nuts trying to figure out what kind of planes they were, why they were so low, why they both made a crazy U-turn at that altitude…so many questions have been racing in my mind.

Comment: Start carrying a camera in case they come back.

Comment: Did you take notice of how many engines these aircraft had? Were they low wing or high wing design?

Comment: "The planes did not show up on flight tracking websites" and "The planes did not appear on radar" are ***extremely*** different statements, and you have no way of saying whether the second statement is true. And it's possible that they would have appeared on ADSBexchange, which very prominently does *not* block military aircraft, even if they weren't on FA or FR24, which do block.

Comment: What does “full-size” mean, other than “not a drone”? How far away were the aircraft in question?

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like the Hail Mary, you can [always ask the FAA what's up?](https://www.faa.gov/noise/inquiries/#other)  They explicitly can't tell you what's going on with military aircraft but if there's a base near you, the FAA suggests you contact that base's noise complaint office.

Probably get nothing, but the worst it'll cost you is an hour of your time.

I'm not aware of Sikorsky seeing much military use, but KCEF's an Air National Guard base not that far to the north.  There's no military use areas on any charts I have for that area.

My money, though, says that if they were super quiet, it's possible they were gliders? There's a glider ops area about halfway between Danbury (DXR) and Sikorsky (BDR) which is roughly where Monroe is, depending on what part. They've got huge wingspan, would be basically silent and while I'm skeptical that you'd make a hard bank turn while under aerotow, they fly pretty slow so I expect their turning radii are pretty tight. It wouldn't shock me at all to learn that two glider pilots decided to fly together for funsies, especially that close to a national park. I bet the views are amazing.